# Vscode Connection to remote server

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server, vscode-remote

I have been trying to login to a remote server using Remote SSH extension and I have been unable to do so.
[image: Screenshot of the VS Code terminal]

I have followed answers to similar questions and have deleted the .vscode-server directory using SSH login throught terminal
After doing that, I again tried to connect to the host but it is stuck at this point

Comment: Make sure the target machine is powerful enough to support this. A basic DigitalOcean server is NOT powerful enough for it.

Comment: I was able to connect to the remote server few days back but I am unable to do it now

Comment: Did you try restarting the remote server? If it's not powerful enough, it will need to be restarted every once in a while. This happened to me a lot when I first started working remotely with VSCode.